# $\langle ab + 1 : a,b \text{ prime}\rangle$ is not a finitely generated subsemigroup of $\Bbb{Z}^{\times}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, semigroups

Let $T \equiv PP + 1 \equiv \{ ab + 1 : a,b \text{ are prime }\} \subset \Bbb{Z}^{\times}$.  Consider the subsemigroup generated by $T$.  How can I show that it is not finitely generated, by that I mean there doesn't exist a finite set of integers $\{z_i\}$ such that each element of $\langle T \rangle$ can be written $t = z_1^{e_1}\cdots z_n^{e_n}$ for some $e_j \geq 0$?

I suppose I could do it by showing that there are infinitely many primes $p = 1 + ab$, but how do I do that?

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson prime numbers and all the unsolved problems therein.

Comment: $ab+1$ is even and hence composite, unless $a$ or $b$ is $2$.  In the latter case, you have [Sophie Germain primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime).  It is conjectured that there are infinitely many of those.

Comment: In other words, I'm out of luck... :'|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you only need to show that there are infinitely many primes dividing numbers in $T$.  To start, let $S$ be a finite set of primes and compare $\pi_2(x)$ with how many numbers less than $x$ are products of primes in $S$.

Comment: What's $\pi_2(x)$?

Comment: The number of semiprimes less than $x$.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/841159/1284

Answer (score 1):

One can show that for each prime $p$ there is a number $ab+1\in T$ with $p\mid ab+1$. As this implies that a generating set must contain a multiple of $p$, $T$ cannot be finitely generated. So, given $p$ pick aprime $b\ne p$ and see what simple condition for $a$ you get ...

Comment: I like this one.  So you're saying pick any prime $p$ and some multiple $m$ such that $pm - 1 = ab$.  Not sure how to do that though.

Comment: Pick a prime $p$ and consider all solutions to $ab = -1 \pmod p$?